# how can I discover the network device type?

Tags: go

On any given computer (OSX, WIn, Lin, etc) there are any number of connected network adapters... whether it's Wi-Fi, BlueTooth, Ethernet or other... And depending on the routing there may be multiple active devices.

In my NARROW use case I want to know what the current CONNECTED default adapter type (Wi-Fi etc...) although once that's known there are easily some others as well as some details.

[Here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/191879/how-to-find-the-currently-connected-network-service-from-the-command-line) is an example shell script that mostly works and converting it to Go is easy enough... it just seems to me there must be a native GO way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [Interfaces()](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Interfaces) from [net](https://golang.org/pkg/net) package

Sample:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    l, err := net.Interfaces()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)

    }
    for _, f := range l {
        if f.Flags&net.FlagUp > 0 {
            fmt.Printf("%s is up\n", f.Name)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was a good idea... The results are different on linux, OSX and Windows.  On Windows I learn weather it's WIFI, ETHERNET or CELLULAR... on Linux I get lo, eth0. I'm looking for the Windows reply so I know what device type.

Comment: @Richard posted an answer regarding Linux specifics — was too much for a comment.

Comment: @rpeshkov sorry if this is too beginner-level question but what is `&` symbol doing between `f.Flags` and `net.FlagUp`? I have never seen this before (not that I have a lot of go experience)

Comment: @JavohirMirzoFazliddinov, it's one of the bitwise operators. Here's some explanation about them: https://yourbasic.org/golang/bitwise-operator-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you'd need to use [the RTNETLINK interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14052883/720999), and there appears to be
[a number of packages](https://www.google.com/search?q=golang+linux+netlink)
which implement wrappers around this layer.

Basically, you'd issue an [`RTM_GETLINK`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html) request and then look at the type of each interface (`ifi_type` field in that manual).
The available types are [here](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.0/source/include/uapi/linux/if_arp.h#L29) — you'd need those which are 802.2 (Ethernet) and 802.11 (Wi-Fi).

---

You could also try to implement a "low-tech" approach by first using
`net.Interfaces()` and then querying their classes by trying to read
a file named "/sys/class/net/{iface_name}/type" (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14063869/720999)). That type is what the `ifi_type` field described above contains.

Note that this approach has some drawbacks:

- Interfaces might came and go anytime, so there's an inherent race between
  obtaining their list via `net.Interfaces()` and querying each interface
  via that `/sys` virtual filesystem.
- That `/sys` filesystem might not be mounted on a particular system.
  That would be quite unusual for a typical desktop or a server system
  but not so much for some "weird" installation (such as embedded etc).